# Laravel script only give 500 server error

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I try to run a script on my server, but only getting page says 500 Server Error.
The server is on Ubuntu 20.04. PHP 8.2 and all required modules is installed.

No error is nginx error.log.

script/storage/logs/laravel.log ouput:

> [2022-12-22 17:51:41] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such
> file or directory (SQL: select * from `pages` where `status` = 1 order
> by `page_order` asc)
> {"view":{"view":"/var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/resources/views/_particles/footer.blade.php","data":[]},"exception":"[object]
> (Spatie\LaravelIgnition\Exceptions\ViewException(code: 0):
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from
> `pages` where `status` = 1 order by `page_order` asc) at
> /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:759)

```
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(898): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback()
#1 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(877): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection()
#2 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(721): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->handleQueryException()
#3 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(404): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run()
#4 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2635): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->select()
#5 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2624): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->runSelect()
#6 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(3160): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\{closure}()
#7 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2623): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->onceWithColumns()
#8 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(699): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->get()
#9 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(683): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->getModels()
#10 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/resources/views/_particles/footer.blade.php(11): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->get()
#11 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(109): require('...')
#12 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(110): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem::Illuminate\\Filesystem\\{closure}()
#13 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(58): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->getRequire()
#14 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(70): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine->evaluatePath()
#15 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(139): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get()
#16 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(122): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#17 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(91): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#18 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/resources/views/site_app.blade.php(120): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#19 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(109): require('...')
#20 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(110): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem::Illuminate\\Filesystem\\{closure}()
#21 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(58): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->getRequire()
#22 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(70): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine->evaluatePath()
#23 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(139): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get()
#24 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(122): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#25 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(91): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#26 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/resources/views/errors/404.blade.php(22): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#27 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(109): require('...')
#28 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(110): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem::Illuminate\\Filesystem\\{closure}()
#29 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(58): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->getRequire()
#30 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(70): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine->evaluatePath()
#31 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(139): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get()
#32 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(122): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#33 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(91): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#34 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(69): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#35 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(35): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->setContent()
#36 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php(57): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->__construct()
#37 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php(87): Illuminate\\Routing\\ResponseFactory->make()
#38 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(615): Illuminate\\Routing\\ResponseFactory->view()
#39 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(543): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->renderHttpException()
#40 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(449): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->prepareResponse()
#41 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(366): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->renderExceptionResponse()
#42 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(51): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->render()
#43 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(143): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->handleException()
#44 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#45 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#46 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle()
#47 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#48 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#49 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle()
#50 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#51 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#52 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#53 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#54 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#55 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors->handle()
#56 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#57 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle()
#58 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#59 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#60 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(134): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#61 /var/www/prod/stream.caaymanx.live/public/index.php(51): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#62 {main}
```

I have tried to reinstall composer.

Comment: can you connect to your database from the command line?

Comment: Yes i can. But haven't put in database information in .env file yet, because i am just try to follow the Documentation for install script. And the docs says database information should be filled in when browser get to https://stream.caaymanx.live/public/install
But when i go to this URL i just get the 500 error. File permissions on server i verified OK btw.

Comment: It tries to load the 404 page which seems to require the database to work, which might indicate you missed something in the install procedure

Comment: Remove "public" from your URL... https://stream.caaymanx.live/install/ works

Comment: Yes, you are right. Why is so? The "install" folder is inside the "public" folder.
Should the nginx conf file point root to stream.caaymanx.live/ or to stream.caaymanx.live/public ?

I have pointed root to stream.caymanx.live/public because the app folder dosent contain any index file. But the docs says i should point root to stream.caaymanx.live/. When i do that i only get 403 forbidden error. Maybe i'm doing som wrong in the nginx conf file..

Comment: The public folder is the document Root  folder from the laravel application. all other folders should not be public. so that is where the domain should point to.

Comment: Format the output using code formatting, not block quote formatting, to make it more readable